# What is the best estimate for the radius of Shoemaker-Levy 9?

Tags: comets, tidal-forces

I have been digging through various scientific articles on modelling the breakup of SL9 to attempt to ascertain its intial size, yet the various estimates vary tremendously.

A radius of 700 m - 1000 m is a common estimate, but some have predicted 2000 m - 2500 m (and even higher).

I know there cannot be "consensus" on such a matter, as the comet was never directly observed before its tidal disruption in July 1992, but what is the best estimate and/or accepted range for the radius of the comet?

Comment: It might be impossible to come up with a consensus on the "best" estimate; those who were well-versed in the art of comet radius estimation all likely argued their estimate was "best" otherwise they wouldn't have offered it. What might be easier to answer in a fact-based way here in Stack Exchange would be a question about the assumptions that went into each of those estimates. To that tend, it might be a good idea to add some links to where those estimates were cited.

Comment: @uhoh thanks a lot for your comment. When I am not rushing to finish my final year project I will come back and post some links to the articles!